# How to create a view of the most popular nodes?

Tags: views, 9

How to create a view of the most popular nodes?

I went through the filter criteria looking for something such as "most read" or "most visited" or "most popular" but I didn't find such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal needs a way to collect information from usage of a site to determine which content is popular and then a way to expose this data to other modules. The included [Statistics module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/statistics/statistics-module-overview) provides this functionality.

Comment: Alright, after enabling that module what I found is a **sort** criteria about number of views, but not a **filter** criteria.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are asking. You seem to be supposing a feature exists in Drupal. In what way would filtering be any different than being about to sort and limiting the count?

Comment: Cilefen, I don't know, but I assume that if you sort randomly, the backend logic of what you sort is still the same, but if your criteria is random, then the backend logic of what you sort would be different and you will have a higher chance to get different items in the View.

Comment: I do not understand any part of that comment.