Where could I see a table of the most viewed nodes?
In Drupal 10.2.4 with Statistics core module installed and node view count activated, I want to see a table of the most viewed nodes like this:
node 1  | alias (if any) | 601 views
node 8  | alias (if any) | 253 views
node 16 | alias (if any) | 112 views
node 5  | alias (if any) | 91 views
node 80 | alias (if any) | 28 views

When I visit a node I normally see something like NUMBER OF views but I that's not what I am asking about here. What I do ask about here is a table, preferably of all nodes altogether with just adjacent number of views for each node. How to get that?

With Views, of course. I’m not posting that without detail as an answer. This was asked at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/313068/how-to-create-a-view-of-the-most-popular-nodes but not fully answered.


Enable the Statistics core module
Enable the Count content views setting from its configuration page (/admin/config/system/statistics)
Create a simple Content view with the default Title field and whatever display format you want
A "content statistics" category should appear in the "fields", "filter criteria," and "sort criteria" which provides three items: "Most recent view", "Total views", and "Views today"
The one you're looking for is "Total views"

